# Error with Python and Instagram API when searching for hashtag

Tags: python, instagram, hashtag

I would like to find out the ten Instagram users that posted most pictures with a certain hashtag.

---

I am using python 2.7, and I wrote this:

```
import urllib, json
from collections import Counter

def GetNumberPics():
    urlInstagram = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/HASHTAG?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN"
    response = urllib.urlopen(urlInstagram)
    return json.loads(response.read())['data']['media_count']

def GetPics(url):
    urlInstagram = url
    response = urllib.urlopen(urlInstagram)
    pics = json.loads(response.read())
    return pics
```

---

in this next piece I find out how many pictures are on Instagram with that hashtag, and I divide it by 20. This because, as far as I understood, it is the number of picture data that I'll receive on each API call. So by doing this I should understand how many times I would have to make the API call to get the data of all pictures.

```
nPics = GetNumberPics()
print nPics
times = nPics / 20
print times

FirstUrl =  'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/HASHTAG/media/recent?client_id=CLIENTID'
pics = GetPics(FirstUrl)
```

---

making a list of all users:

```
users = []
for i in range(20):
    users.append(pics['data'][i]['user']['username'])
```

---

getting the next url, as received in the first api call:

```
nextUrl = pics['pagination']['next_url']
```

---

making the api call for the times calculated before - I'm printing `i` just to see how many times I do the API call.

```
for i in range(times):
        print i
        pics = GetPics(nextUrl)
        for l in range(len(pics['data'])):
            users.append(pics['data'][l]['user']['username'])
        nextUrl = pics['pagination']['next_url']
```

---

counting the users and printing out the ten users that used the most that hashtag:

```
counts = Counter(users)
print(counts).most_common(10)
```

---

I get an error which I can't understand, when I arrive to the 89th call, when using the hashtag "inerasmus":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michele\Desktop\programming\EIE\tweetNumber.py", line 55, in <module>
    nextUrl = pics['pagination']['next_url']
KeyError: 'next_url'
```

I hope it is a useful question also for someone else. Thank you very much!

Comment: You reached the last page?

Comment: I don't think so - there should be 103 pages as number of pictures / 20 - I am using the account @inErasmus as a feedback, all its pictures has that hashtag so it should pop out in my list, but when I tried to search for 88 times it doesn't count all its pictures.. I hope I was able to explain myself

Comment: All info I can find suggests that `next_url` is only set if there is actually a next page. If it is missing, you ran out of pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use their [Python API](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/)? From what I see, you can do all of this with the python library. Also, there are already some people on Github that have messed around with the API. [Here is one](https://github.com/gopar/Instabot/) and [another.](https://github.com/gangverk/InstagramDjango)

Comment: Sorry, meant to put this as a comment and not an answer. This doesn't answer your question.